# Fill a matrix of known size in an omp loop. Size of entries unknown

Tags: c++, multithreading, matrix, memory-management, openmp

I need to fill a matrix ( `std::vector< std::vector<T> >` ) whose number of rows and columns is known and already set by using the `vector::resize( ... )` function.

The objects of each matrix element are objects of the `class T`, which are supposed to have an `std::set<int>` as a member among others. There is no way to know the size of these sets in advance.

To fill the matrix I aim to use a loop like the following, where m, n are known numbers:

```
std::vector< T > innerVector;
innerVector.resize( n, T() );

std::vector< std::vector< T > > myMatrix;
myMatrix.resize( m, innerVector );

#pragma omp parallel for
for( size_t i = 0; i < myMatrix.size(); ++i )
{
    for( size_t j = 0; j < myMatrix.at(0).size(); ++j )
    {
        fillMatrix( myMatrix, i, j);
    }
}
```

The `fillMatrix( ... )` function does only use already known information to build the set of numbers contained in each matrix element, so there is no data dependency there.

Filling the matrix like this we do not run into race conditions caused by multiple threads accessing a matrix element at a time. My question is whether it is safe to call the `fillMatrix( ... )` function without using an `omp critical` enviroment.

The point is I do not know how the `vector::resize( ... )` function works. Somehow it is assigning some memory for `myMatrix`, but as the size of the elements of the `class T` is unknown, I can imagine running into the situation, where the originally assigned memory for a matrix element is not enough. What happens then? Is it possible that multiple threads (i.e. threads filling different matrix entries) try to extend the assigned memory using the same address?

Answer (score 1):

Many complex objects such as `std::vector` and `std::set` consist of a memory for the object itself (i.e. `sizeof(std::vector)` bytes) and additional dynamically allocated memory behind it. For your example, the set elements are usually stored in dynamically allocated nodes of a tree. So if you do a `std::vector<T>::resize(n)`, the vector will make sure that it's own dynamically allocated memory can contain `n` objects of type `T` who each include a set. It will *default-construct* those elements using this When you later add elements to the sets inside of `T`, new memory blocks will be allocated for the set's tree nodes.

The way you describe it, you should be fine in terms of correctness. However, I would strongly recommend you to clarify this in the interface:

```
void fillMatrix(T&, size_t, size_t);
...
fillMatrix(myMatrix[i][j], i, j);
```

Or even:

```
T fillMatrix(size_t, size_t);
...
myMatrix[i][j] = fillMatrix(i, j);
```

This way, it is much clearer that `fillMatrix` doesn't mess data from other threads.

A general recommendation in shared memory programming is to allocate and initialize memory on the thread that is likely to later work with that memory. So if you will do more `parallel for` on `myMatrix`, consider the following:

```
std::vector< std::vector< T > > myMatrix;
myMatrix.resize( m );

#pragma omp parallel for
for( size_t i = 0; i < myMatrix.size(); ++i )
{
    myMatrix.at( i ).resize( n ); // Ommiting T() is a bit more efficient
    for( size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j )
    {
        fillMatrix( myMatrix, i, j);
    }
}
```

However, in any case the code will probably be constrained by memory allocation (both for adding elements to `std::set` and `std::vector::resize`). So you should not expect a parallel performance increase on that particular part of the code unless `fillMatrix` does significant additional computation. However, the data may be in caches / NUMA-nodes close to the thread computing on the elements, so the rest of your parallel code can compute efficiently.